# mySql joining table best practices?

Tags: mysql

I am building a web app which has numerous types of objects and numerous relationships between those objects.  Each type of object I've given a 3-digit code (i.e. "TRA", "COM", "APR", "CRI" etc.).   I have a joining table which asks for the type and then the type_id of a primary and secondary object which should be linked together.

```
CREATE TABLE `obj_rels` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pri_type` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`pri_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`sec_type` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`sec_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`effective_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`trashed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`trashed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `types` (`pri_type`,`sec_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've played with numerous different types of indexes, but the queries on this table are slowing down the application.

Entries are added only once, so a relationship would be defined with only one record such as pri_type = FIL, pri_type_id = 123, sec_type = TRA, sec_type_id = 456... If I need to search for anything related to a specific TRA, it therefore needs to search both the primary and secondary type/type_id to find them.  The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT pri_type, pri_type_id, sec_type, sec_type_id, effective_on, trashed_by, trashed_on 
    FROM obj_rels 
    UNION 
    SELECT sec_type AS pri_type, sec_type_id AS pri_type_id, pri_type AS sec_type, pri_type_id AS sec_type_id, effective_on, trashed_by, trashed_on 
    FROM obj_rels 
) AS qry 
WHERE pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375 AND (trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on))
```

But this query takes almost 1.5 seconds to run with about 71,000 records in the table, and other queries I have are dependent on this one, so they are taking 4-5 seconds to run.

How can I best setup the indexes or tweak the query to optimize the results of relationships?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest you'll get with your current table design is eliminating the subquery AND the union altogether, and using IF statements to get your dynamic columns, like this:

```
SELECT
    IF(pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375, pri_type, sec_type) AS pri_type,
    IF(pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375, pri_type_id, sec_type_id) AS pri_type_id,
    IF(pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375, sec_type, pri_type) AS sec_type,
    IF(pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375, sec_type_id, pri_type_id) AS sec_type_id,
    effective_on,
    trashed_by,
    trashed_on 
FROM obj_rels 
WHERE (trashed_on = 0 OR trashed_on IS NULL)
    AND (
        (pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375)
        OR (sec_type = 'TRA' AND sec_type_id = 21375)
    );
```

This will result in 1/2 as many rows as unioning the table with itself, and will avoid nasty temp tables for that big cluster of nasty data.

Of course, you'll get SIGNIFICANTLY FASTER if you index your search columns:

```
ALTER TABLE obj_rels
    ADD INDEX (pri_type),
    ADD INDEX (pri_type_id),
    ADD INDEX (sec_type),
    ADD INDEX (sec_type_id),
    ADD INDEX (trashed_on);
```

PS - Note that I changed your `ISNULL` function call to `trashed_on IS NULL`.  The former is a `COALESCE` alias (COALESCE is preferred, btw, because it works in other RDBMSes), the latter is a comparison.  If you wanted to use the former, you could say `WHERE COALESCE(trashed_on, 0) = 0`, to handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

UNION can be useful to combine between two simpler, indexable queries. You can eliminate the table-scan, and combine two smaller interim results after applying the respective WHERE clauses, which benefit from two different indexes.

But you've misunderstood this technique. The way you're doing it reads *every* row in the table twice, creating a temporary table of 142,000 rows, and then applying your conditions to that temp table.

So write the query this way instead:

```
(
  SELECT pri_type, pri_type_id, sec_type, sec_type_id, effective_on, trashed_by, trashed_on 
  FROM obj_rels 
  WHERE pri_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type_id = 21375 AND trashed_on IS NULL
)

UNION ALL

(
  SELECT sec_type, sec_type_id, pri_type, pri_type_id, effective_on, trashed_by, trashed_on 
  FROM obj_rels
  WHERE sec_type = 'TRA' AND sec_type_id = 21375 AND trashed_on IS NULL
)
```

It may seem counter-intuitive to repeat similar WHERE clauses instead of writing one WHERE clause, but the purpose is to use the respective indexes to reduce the set of matched rows, then UNION these smaller sets of rows. That's much better than creating a temp table with 2x the total number of rows in your table, then applying a WHERE clause to the temp table.

To optimize each subquery, create these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE obj_rels
 ADD KEY (pri_type_id, pri_type, trashed_on),
 ADD KEY (sec_type_id, sec_type, trashed_on);
```

Each query in the UNION uses the respective index.

I put the `type_id` columns first because I assume they're more selective than the `type` columns.

I would also make changes to the application to ensure that trashed_on is never 0. Just use NULL if there's no valid datetime. The reason is to allow the index to include trashed_on. I'm not sure if it'll apply the index to the more complex expression using `OR`.

Using UNION ALL instead of UNION eliminates the step where the UNION sorts the total result to eliminate duplicates. Disregard that change if you *want* to eliminate duplicates.